# Paypal IPN continuously hits my IPN page w/the same transaction

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I just moved my server to a new host, and obviously changed the DNS for my paypal ipn page.

For some reason paypal keeps hitting my page about every 30 seconds with the same transactions over and over again.

So of course its verified then stored in the database as duplicate records.

Has anyone had this problem?  Or know how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your browser is returning 200 OK status to paypal.

Either way, you should store IPN tracking IDs (ipn_track_id) in your database and check for duplicates. This is the only guaranteed way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to PayPal's IPN documntation:

> **Your listener must respond to each message, whether or not you intend
> to do anything with it. If you do not respond, PayPal assumes that the
> message was not received and resends the message.** PayPal continues to
> resend the message periodically until your listener sends the
> correct message back, although the interval between resent
> messages increases each time. The message can be resent for up to four
> days.
>
> This resend algorithm can lead to situations in which PayPal
> resends the IPN message while you are sending back the original
> message. In this case, you should send your response again, to cover
> the possibility that PayPal did not actually receive your response the
> first time. You should also ensure that you do not process the
> transaction associated with the message twice.
>
> IMPORTANT: PayPal
> expects to receive a response to an IPN message within 30 seconds.
> Your listener should not perform time-consuming operations, such as
> creating a process, before responding to the IPN message.

So a) is your script properly responding and b) is the notify_url parameter from your transaction different with your DNS change?